# How to configure PEP Proxy - Wilma Config.js for securing fiware orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma

we have deployed a dedicated orion instance based on image in cloud Fiware Lab section.
we need to add Pep proxy Wilma for authentication and authorization security to our backend applications.
in the same dedicated instance we have installed Node.js and we have followed all steps given in [[[http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/PEP_Proxy_-*Wilma*-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide]]](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/PEP_Proxy_-_Wilma_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide]]).

The Problem:

how should we configure the config.js in order to direct Orion end services clients into pep proxy wilma ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imagine that, originally, Orion was listening in port A. You have to do the following:

1. Change Orion listening port to port B
2. Configure PEP to listen in port A
3. Configure PEP with app_port = B

This way the Orion clients will send the requests to PEP instead of the Orion. And PE will redirect the valid requests to Orion new port.